# How to configure Hibernate Search to batch fetching rows in database?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search to implement a full text search. My database is SQL Server.
Unfortunately, when my full text search retrieves too much documents, I face the limitation of SQL Server :

`The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters`.

Indeed, after having found matching documents, Hibernate Search tries to load corresponding entities from the database, with a single query and a too big IN clause.

So my question is, is it possible to configure Hibernate Search to fetch entities in batches from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to check the [fetch size](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-query-fetch-size) from loading options which allow you to set how many entities are loaded in a single trip to DB, something like:

```
SearchResult<Book> result = searchSession.search( Book.class ) 
        .where( f -> f.match()
                .field( "title" )
                .matching( "robot" ) )
        .loading( o -> o.fetchSize( 50 ) ) 
        .fetch( 200 );
```

Also, if you expect to work with large result sets, you might want to check the [scrolling](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-query-fetching-results-scrolling) instead.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate Search 5.11.10.Final, so this API is not available.

I found this ticket https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-962 saying that this feature is only available in Hibernate Search 6.x.

So I'm trying to migrate to this version.